# Why do python module names have some uppercase letters but are always imported in lowercase?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Whenever I see references to modules like SciPy and NumPy the first letter of each part is capitalized. However they must be imported with all lowercase letters. Why is there this difference?

Comment: The CamelCase names are "brand names." They have nothing to do with Python the language.

Comment: SciPy and NumPy are project names. The code that comprises them follows Python naming conventions which specify lower case modules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is basically in branding. As per the style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names module names should be short and all lower cased. One reason for that is that when you are importing a module, it would be inconvenient if you had to remember all the capitalizations in the name. Big packages like NumPy and SciPy follow this convention, but when they are referring to themselves (or when others are referring to them) they like to include the stylistic capitalizations. It's mostly a style/branding choice.