# ModuleNotFoundError when I am trying to import package

Tags: python

my_controller.py is as follow:

```
from models import Person

david = Person('David')
```

And my project structure is

```
app
├── controller
│   └── my_controller.py
│   
└── models
    └── __init__.py
    └── person.py
```

I must do something wrong because I keep get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

What is the correct way to import class Person to my_controller.py?

PS I am working on ubuntu

Comment: try `app.models`, maybe that would work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709325/why-do-python-module-names-have-some-uppercase-letters-but-are-always-imported-i/50709376#50709376 Try import person

Comment: Try running script from `app` directory using `python -m controller.my_controller`

Comment: ok got it : should we be aware of what is contained in __init.py__ ?

Comment: Can you add the the python command that you use to run the `app`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative import

```
from . import models
```

Or it's better to import models that you will user, since it won't visually collide with django.db.models.

```
from django import forms
from .models import VolunteerBasicInfo

class BasicInfoCollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = VolunteerBasicInfo
        ...
```

You also don't need to user brackets with class `Meta`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have `app` as a package and `controllers` and `models` as different modules.

To implement the package structure, you need to have `__init__.py` in the root that is `app` here and `__init__.py` inside every module.

After that, you can import one module functions/classes inn other modules without the need of relative import.

I tested the same structure that is present in the question with above suggestion.

The structure looks like this:

```
├── app
├── __init__.py
├── controllers
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── my_c.py
└── models
   ├── __init__.py
   └── my_m.py
```

- All the `__init__.py` are empty.
- The content of `my_m.py` is:

```
class Person:
    def test_model(self):
        x = "Model Imported"
        return x
```

- The content of `my_c.py` is:

```
from models.my_m import Person

test = Person()
print(test.test_model())
```

- When you execute:

  - `python3 -m controllers.my_c` inside app
- Output is:

  - `Model Imported`

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change any of the structure and you want to execute `my_controller.py` you will need to append access to the common folder so it can import any of the adjacent modules.

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
))

from models.person import Person

x = Person()
```

Comment: I do mind to change the structure. What is the best practice?

Comment: The ideal is to have a branching, having a parent folder only depend on children modules and not adjacent ones, but if you make `app/app.py` the execution point it will allow the circular import, something that is common thing on flask/django;is not that bad but is half half code style choice than a best practice thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running the file in the shell its pretty simple. The idea is you want to start it from what your "root" directory is in the project.

First, add an empty `__init__.py` file in the `app/` directory.

Second, change your import in `my_controller.py` to `from models.person`, instead of just `from models`:

```py
from models.person import Person

david = Person('David')
```

Last, cd into the `app/` directory, and run this bad boy.

```sh
$ python3 -m controller.my_controller.py
```

If that doesn't work, then set your `PYTHONPATH` to `/app` as well, like so:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/dir/app/venv/bin
```

and then attempt the first bash command again.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder structure is the following...

```
app
├── __init__.py
│   
├── controller
│   └── my_controller.py
│   └── __init__.py
│   
└── models
    └── __init__.py
    └── person.py
```

And your root is the `app` folder, you can use in `my_controller.py`...

```
from app.models.person import Person

if __name__ == '__main__':
    david = Person('David')
```

Then if you run the program in the shell, you first navigate to the parent folder of `app` and use...

```
PYTHONPATH=. python app/controller/my_controller.py
```

It seems you are missing a `__init__.py` in the `app` and the `controller` folder as well as the correct import path.

**Why using this approach**

`__init__.py` files are necessary to treat the code in other folders as Python modules and allow for import. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not necessary but good practise, read more e.g. [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/). Now you might ask yourself what does `PYTHONPATH=.` mean. It sets the folder from where you execute your code as root. Using that, you need `from <root>.<subfolder>.<file> import <class>` as import paths. This helps you keeping a clean import structure, that shows the full scope of your project and makes adding a `tests` folder an ease :)

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

[Directory Structure like yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EQRQ.png)

when I tried this out, at first I got the same error as yours
and after many attempts of debugging it, I found out one of my **_*init**_*.py contains some unusual code that I didn't add and it was :`from models import person`

so when I removed it from there , It run successfully but only when I am running it from the root directory as shown in the image below.

Even I tried several ways to run it from current working directory by changing the cwd to "app" or in my case "practice" but then it started showing me an error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`
'

But for Now, I hope you get the solution...

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T31b.png)

Note:=you'll see several other files as well , It was added by my IDE or python itself. so you don't need to worry about adding those files.

code in my_controller.py:-

`from app.models import person`

`person.first()`

and person.py module contains a function named first()

IDE USED:- PyCharm